# Maintain PHP session in Facebook AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook, session

I have a Facebook iframe app. As soon as the app authorisation is confirmed I grab some data from the signed request an put it into session:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
    if(empty($data["user_id"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='$auth_url'</script>");
        exit;
    }
    $_SESSION['fb_id'] = $data['user_id'];
?>
```

Simple, right?  So now the user can interact with my app, and the final user action triggers an AJAX request.  I'm using jQuery for this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'include/handler.php',
    data:'name=value',
    success: function(msg) {
        alert("Success: "+msg);
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        alert("Fail: "+msg);    
    }
});
```

So then in handler.php, I need to use that previously saved session value, but the session is empty.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['fb_id'];
?>
```

Obviously these code snippets are simplified, but can anyone explain this to me? I've got a feeling that I'm doing something stupid, but it's been a long day.

Comment: Are the ajax calls using the same session? Getting a new session each time would appear as the fb_id variable not "sticking", since it was set in some other session.

Comment: I had to presume they weren't last night, and gave up on sessions altogether in the end. I've worked around the problem by not using session at all, but I'd still be grateful for an explanation of why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is down to an issue with the shared hosting environment I was using.  For whatever reason, requests originating from AJAX or Flash are handled with a unique session id.  The fix was simply to move to a different hosting provider.

Comment: To further clarify: I don't know if the strange session behaviour was due to a setting with the old provider, but with a different host and testing locally the session data works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax({
  ...,
  cache: false,
  ...
});
If you are using IE, this might be the problem as IE caches ajax requests. Or, if the facebook graph api request is run at the same time as the ajax request, there might be some timing issues.

Comment: Sorry, the problem happens in all browsers and the request is made on user interaction when there shouldn't be any api requests active.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass to handler.php the Facebook ID?

```
...
url:'include/handler.php?fb_id=<?php $_SESSION['fb_id']?>',
```

And in handler.php, check for both the session and the passed variable.

Comment: The goal was to not pass anything except the user-provided form data through the Ajax request.  This has since being rectified by taking a different approach, but I'd still welcome an explaination of why $_SESSION would be empty in my original example.